# I am new to GTK3 CSS. Is there a way to have different headerbar textures for specific applications?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, gtk3, css

I am attempting to modify a theme named "Poppy OS X" to recreate Mac OS X Mountain Lion. I am trying to get custom textures on the headerbar of certain windows (Leather textures on Notes, Calendar, To Do, wood on Lutris, etc) but it will not work on anything besides than Calendar.
Here is a *mockup* of what it is supposed to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bfH5.jpg
and here is what it actually looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ENwX.jpg

This is the CSS I am using:

````
.titlebar:not(headerbar) {
    min-height: 22px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    color: #3c3c3c;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("Resources/ArtFile.bin/GKToolbar/CalendarLeatherSmol.png"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #e9e9e9, #b2b2b2);
    box-shadow: inset 0  1px #f1f1f1,
                inset 0 -2px alpha(#fff, 0.085),
                inset 0 -1px alpha(#000, 0.38);
}
window.org-gnome-Calendar headerbar.titlebar:backdrop,
.titlebar:not(headerbar):backdrop {
    color: #909090;
    background-image: url("Resources/ArtFile.bin/GKToolbar/CalendarLeatherSmol.png"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #fafafa, #d6d6d6);
    box-shadow: inset 0  1px #fbfbfb,
                inset 0 -2px alpha(#fff, 0.085),
                inset 0 -1px alpha(#000, 0.31);
}

window.org-gnome-ToDo headerbar.titlebar,
.titlebar:not(headerbar) {
    min-height: 22px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    color: #3c3c3c;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("Resources/ArtFile.bin/GKToolbar/RemindersLeather.png"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #e9e9e9, #b2b2b2);
    box-shadow: inset 0  1px #f1f1f1,
                inset 0 -2px alpha(#fff, 0.085),
                inset 0 -1px alpha(#000, 0.38);
}
window.org-gnome-ToDo headerbar.titlebar:backdrop,
.titlebar:not(headerbar):backdrop {
    color: #909090;
    background-image: url("Resources/ArtFile.bin/GKToolbar/RemindersLeather.png"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #fafafa, #d6d6d6);
    box-shadow: inset 0  1px #fbfbfb,
                inset 0 -2px alpha(#fff, 0.085),
                inset 0 -1px alpha(#000, 0.31);
}

window.org-gnome-Notes headerbar.titlebar,
.titlebar:not(headerbar) {
    min-height: 22px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    color: #3c3c3c;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("Resources/ArtFile.bin/GKToolbar/NoteLeather.png"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #e9e9e9, #b2b2b2);
    box-shadow: inset 0  1px #f1f1f1,
                inset 0 -2px alpha(#fff, 0.085),
                inset 0 -1px alpha(#000, 0.38);
}
window.org-gnome-Notes headerbar.titlebar:backdrop,
.titlebar:not(headerbar):backdrop {
    color: #909090;
    background-image: url("Resources/ArtFile.bin/GKToolbar/NoteLeather.png"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #fafafa, #d6d6d6);
    box-shadow: inset 0  1px #fbfbfb,
                inset 0 -2px alpha(#fff, 0.085),
                inset 0 -1px alpha(#000, 0.31);
}```

**The Calendar lines are working, but everything else is not.**
````